# Can't list (non-PostGIS) tables on a remote Postgresql db schema with QGis

Tags: postgresql, remote-access, qgis

I need to connect QGis to a remote Postgres database. My client does not have a fix IP so I avoid using pg_hba.conf. I use a ssh tunnel with a dedicated unix user (`qgis_user`) and ssh keys:

```
ssh -L 5444:localhost:5432 qgis_user@my_remote_host.com
```

It works, I can create in QGis a postgres remote connection on `localhost:5444`.

My problem is that I see the list of schemas of the remote database, but I can't list the tables within the schemas.

Note : in this connection to the remote db, I use the same remote postgres user as usual, who is the owner of the database.

To test, I created in QGis a postgres connection on my local database using `localhost:5432`. It works, I can see the schemas, list the tables and issue SQL queries.

If I use psql on my local machine

```
psql -U my_remote_pg_user -W -h localhost -p 5444 -d my_remote_pg_database
```

it works fine, I'm on the remote db and can choose a schema, list the tables and issue SQL queries as usual.

In both cases, QGis issues a warning saying that postgis is not installed, but a priori, I don't need it because I only want to access to regular tables (not PostGIS).

I tried to install the postgis extension (on local and remote postgres), but it didn't change.

I also tried to use the public schema on the remote postgres, no change.

My environment is:
QGis 3.34
Debian 11 (remote and local)
Postgres 16.1 (remote and local)

```
SELECT version();
### local
PostgreSQL 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
### remote
PostgreSQL 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
```

The fact that the local psql can select data on the remote database seems to indicate that the problem is on QGis side. I tried to find a QGis setting which could help, but found nothing useful.

Comment: Your ssh command doesn't make sense.  It would be connecting to a host named qgis_user, not as a user named qgis_user.

Comment: Oh yes, this is confusing, sorry. In fact, `qgis_user` corresponds to an entry in my local `~/.ssh/config`. This is confusing because the entry in my local `~/.ssh/config` has the same name as my remote unix user.

I edited the question to replace

`ssh -L 5444:localhost:5432 qgis_user`

by

`ssh -L 5444:localhost:5432 qgis_user@my_remote_host.com`